# Keep tag list when editing questions

Tags: feature-request, questions, tags, edits

When you look at a question, off to the right is the list of tags on it, including the number of tags that exist in the database for each of them (maybe off by some yet-to-be-cached amount).

When I go to edit that question, the tags don't show to the right.  This is one of the things I use when editing to determine whether a tag is worthy of being there (just one of the things).  Please have the question-specific tag list show when editing.

Right now I have to open a new window to relook at the tag list, or backup and start over.

Here's a screenshot of how I'd like it to look.

[image: Tag Edit Mockup]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I like this idea - it would be especially nice when you're trying to see which tags are the more popular variations of tags while retagging.

Answer (score 2):

This isn't a bad idea, but

1. I *guarantee* that people will expect the tags in the sidebar to change dynamically as you edit the tags field.
2. The sidebar help text can be quite large, and changes dynamically, which means the sidebar tags will be bouncing around like a rubber ball as you move from field to field.

I generally dislike "improvements" that will result in even more work, and seem likely to beget even more bugs and feature-requests of their own ... for what is essentially a minor cosmetic improvement.

Answer (score 1):

The input element where you enter the tags uses an autocomplete prompt that will show you how many instances of a tag there are.

Comment: Yes, but the tags are already there, so I'd have to basically reenter them to see the count.

Comment: @Lance: yeah, you can't see what tags the question currently has. It would be nice if the current tags stayed to the right so we would be accurate in our retagging.

Answer (score 0):

I have the same problem, but... I really don't want any more clutter on the edit page.

Ctrl + back button is good enough.

Comment: Seems like it would fit good right under the 'How to Edit' box.

Comment: Maybe. You should fake a screenshot...

Comment: OK, screenshot faked.

Comment: Good, good... Looks reasonably clean.