# No 'start a bounty' link on question

Tags: support, bug, status-completed, bounties

I wanted to start a bounty on [**this question**](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/39512/keep-tag-list-when-editing-questions) but I don't have a `start a bounty` link.  I don't have any of the problems [noted here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/54726/missing-start-a-bounty-link-on-stackoverflow/54772#54772), my last bounty question was completed (manually) yesterday.

Comment: I don't see a link either.

Comment: This likely has something to do with the interaction between the old bounty system (there is an old-style bounty on that question) and the new system.

Comment: I have 659 rep on stackoverflow, just created a question, can't see "add bounty" link.  Help?  (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4129622/connecting-to-twitter-streaming-api-with-tracks-with-spaces-using-apache-httpclie)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As [Jon](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/136558/jon-seigel) suggested, there was a bug in the bounty display code for old bounty questions.

This has been fixed and will be deployed tonight.

Comment: Thanks, it fixed it, but then my picture disappeared and I had to edit it back in.

Answer (score 3):

For people who wander by here:

> A bounty can be started on a question two days after the question was asked.

See [How does the bounty system work?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/16065/how-does-the-bounty-system-work)